# Linux - created processes

Tags: linux, shell, process, ssh, ps

I'm new to Linux Shell and kind of stuck at an assignment:
We're supposed to connect to a linux machine using ssh. Then we should issue the ls command and use ps and pstree to see what processes we're created in the machine to make the ls command work. Then we need to find out the RUIDs and EUIDs of these processes. And to explain what files have been accessed on the way and why.

I know there's a lot of documentation on shell commands in the net, so of course I tried solving the problem using google first. I found out how to list all the processes with ps -ef and also how to get the RUID or EUID for a specific process.
But how can I see the processes that help me achieve the ls command? If I do ls first and then ps, the ls process has already finished and the only active processes are the ps and ssh processes...
Also I have no idea what files are meant in the assignment.

Comment: Instead of googling start reading the man pages typical for all unix like systems. For any command (for example `ls`) just type `man ls` and you find an exact description of that command with all its options in a version that _exactly_ matches your system. That is the most precise documentation you can get.

Comment: For the files accessed in the process: consider what happens when you login: what processes might access what files to decide if you are to be granted access? And what is the first process that is started for you? What initialization files does that process typically read? And might there also be some log entries being written? Where to? ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that `ls` take at least some time. You can try `ls -R` (recursive) of a directory with some data in it. Once you have found a suitable directory (use `/` as last resort but that could be *very* long) launch `ls` and `ps` through `ssh`, with `ls` sent to background:

```
$ ssh host "ls -R >>/dev/null & pstree -u user" | grep ls
sshd---bash-+-ls
```

You see that a `sshd` process was created, along with a `bash` process, and finally a `ls` process.

To find the EUID and RUID; use the following construct:

```
$ ssh host "ls -R >> /dev/null & ps -o ruid,euid -p \$!"
 RUID  EUID
  501   501
```

Note that `$!` returns the pid of the last command (here `ls`) and it needs to be escaped with `\` because we do not want it to resolve on the local computer but rather on the remote one.

To find which files are opened, you can use the same construct with `strace` or `lsof` rather than `ps` (left as exercice, see `man strace`, `man lsof`) on each process in the sequence (`sshd`, `bash`, `ls`), and maybe also the local `ssh` command.

Comment: `lsof` can generate lists of open files too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I considered `lsof`, but it would only list files opened at the time `lsof` is run. `lsof -p $(pgrep -u user bash|head -1)` typically does not list `.bashrc` for instance.

Comment: OK: fair comment.  Perhaps worth mentioning — rejected solutions that are superficially usable can be helpful.  Groping through the `strace` output is not fun, either, but it will cover all the files that are opened.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer. Note that `strace ... |& grep ^read` gets the job mostly done.

Comment: What do you mean with "use / as last resort"? Unfortunately, there's only one directory and one file, so I think the ls process finishes to fast.

Comment: I meant running `ls -R /`  might take a long time and it will try to read directories for which you do not have reading permissions. I'm pretty much certain you can find more files on that computer. Another option is to suspend ls immediately after run: `ls -R & kill -SIGSTOP $!`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still lost - my experience with Linux is close to non existent. Am I supposed to type exactly ssh host "ls -R >>/dev/null & pstree -u user" | grep ls? Or just ls -R >>/dev/null & pstree -u user with my user name? The first doesn't work and the second doesn't list ls. If I use ls -R >>/dev/null & pstree -u user | grep ls I get an syntax error...

Comment: What about the accessed files?

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion that the person setting the assignment didn't really think this through or try it out.

`ls` completes *really* quickly, on any machine that's not stuck in a 1980s timewarp, so how are you supposed to slow it down? Using a debugger? That's an advanced technique.

Furthermore, I'll let you into a secret about which processes are launched to make the `ls` command work... `ls`. **That's it**. Again, unless this is some weird throwback to the 1980s that I've never heard of.

Complain to the person who set the assignment.